# How to use macros in TI Code Composer Studio?

Tags: assembly, macros

Here is my macro:

```
 _st_jmp_always .macro target, dir
    jmp targetdir
    .endm
```

Here is what the compiler returns:
subdir_rules.mk:7: recipe for target 'main.obj' failed
"struct_gas_msp430.inc", ERROR!   at line 16: [E0002] Illegal mnemonic specified
_st_jmp_always .macro target, dir

"struct_gas_msp430.inc", ERROR!   at line 17: [E0001] Undefined symbol
jmp targetdir

"struct_gas_msp430.inc", ERROR!   at line 18: [E0501] No active macro definition
.endm

Comment: It appears that TI Code Composer supports a number of compilers.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using the one provided by TI, not the MSP430 gcc one
ti-cgt-msp430_21.6.0.LTS
It looks like it doesn't expand macro directives

Comment: Finally, I switched from TI's compiler to gcc with makefiles. It works fine.